# Hypothetical very massive particles

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, string-theory, supersymmetry, magnetic-monopoles

I'm looking for a table or compilation of hypothetical very massive ($m\gtrsim 1$ TeV) particles and  their expected masses (or bounds on them or relation with other scales). All I know is (please, correct me if I'm wrong):

1. Supersymmetric particles: $M_{GUT}\gtrsim m\gtrsim 0.1$ TeV.
2. Massive neutrinos related to see-saw mechanism: $m\sim M_{GUT}$.
3. Magnetic monopoles: $M_P\gtrsim m\gtrsim 0.1$ TeV.
4. Dilaton: $M_P\gtrsim m\gtrsim 0.1$ TeV.
5. X bosons in GUT: $m\sim M_{GUT}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add the following:

- The triplet, the SU(5) partner of the Higgs, assuming the Higgs is in a 5 of SU(5), or the analogous thing for higher GUTs. Presumably, this is GUT scale, but the experimental bound on this is going to be weak, order 1TeV, since it comes from loop corrections to the standard model. the triplet will be a scalar charged like a quark doublet.
- Any SU(5) Higgs boson, whatever it might be, or the analogous thing in higher GUTs the theoretical range is GUT scale.

I don't think that compiling a list is so useful--- you will eventually hit manifold moduli fields, and string resonances, and then the black hole spectrum, which is continuously lined to the particle spectrum. There is no limit to what unstable particles you start detecting at the GUT scale. The monopoles are interesting because they are stable. The rest are not.